# Gnuplot: (High blood pressure datapoints): Plot two points against time, difference between them

Tags: visualization, gnuplot

I am newly disgnosed with high blood pressure and need to a) check my bp regularly now and keep a log of it and b) take medicine. You can't help me with b), but I'd need your kind help with a).

I need to keep a log of my blood pressure, therefore I need to take a few readings each day. My log looks like this:

```
20121001 0801 175 101
20121001 0802 Pill
20121001 1017 125 91
20121001 1537 121 101
20121001 1907 117 89
20121002 0758 191 111
20121002 0759 Pill
20121002 1003 117 98
(...)
```

Could you help me out with a `gnuplot` config file that reads the above two datapoints, plots them against the time (`%Y%m%d %H%M`).

The caveat here is the lines "`... Pill`" which I'd like to show up on the plot as a dot, a vertical line or something similar (they simply show when I have taken my pill).

Also, and I'm not quite sure if this is possible, I'd like to visualize the difference between datapoint 1 and datapoint 2, ie. `175-101=74` in the first line.

This would tremendously help me in visualizing if (and if yes, when) my pills start working.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created the following `bash` script. Run it with your log file name as the argument:

```
#! /bin/bash -e
input=$1
start=$(head -n1 "$input")
start=${start:0:9}0000
end=$(tail -n1 "$input")
end=${end:0:9}2359

gnuplot <<EOF
set terminal png
set output 'bp.png'
set xdata time
set timefmt '%Y%m%d %H%M'
set xrange ['$start':'$end']
plot '< grep -v Pill "$input"' using 1:(\$3-\$4):3:4 with errorbars pt 2 title 'Pressure', \
     '< grep    Pill "$input"' using 1:(100) with points lw 2 pt 7 title 'Pill'
EOF
(($?)) && exit 1
display bp.png
```

Comment: Great stuff, works like a charm. Even after "doing the pills" for only a couple of days I can already see that the median drops like a rock after I've taken a pill. Wow. Thank you!

Comment: Now, I don't want to sound greedy, but do seeing the graph I guess it would be nice to have the median-dots (and maybe even the upper and lower readings) connected by a curve-fitting line of sort. Something along the lines (haha, pun intended) of the `pseudo-3d multi-branch fit to velocity data` example on http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/fit.html

Answer (score 0):

I will answer the second part of your question. Therefor, I updated your file to have something to log.

```
 1  20121001 0801 175 101
 2  20121001 0802 Pill
 3  20121001 1017 125 91
 4  20121001 1537 121 101
 5  20121001 1907 117 89
 6  20121002 0758 191 111
 7  20121002 0759 Pill
 8  20121002 1003 117 98
```

The gnuplot script looks like this

```
plot "< grep -v Pill meas2" using 1:($4-$5) with line, \
     "< grep Pill meas2" using 1:($2*0) ps 10 pt 8
```

Where the inputlines not containing `Pill` are selected. You can use `$4-$5` to perform the calculation. The other plot plots a symbol at the horizontal axis on the times where pill is in the line.

For the first part, I found some hints: http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/datetime-e.html

Comment: Thanks, I tried inserting your plot-script into choroba's bash-script (just to get a better understanding of any given tool I always try every answer I get!), but I get an error: `line 0: invalid expression`, it points to the closing parenthesis of the `(...)using 1:(-) with line(...)`-statement. This is on Mac OS X using `macport`'s gnuplot `plot (GNU plotutils) 2.6`, btw.

Comment: @Christian: You have to backslash the dollar signs.

Comment: `line 0: warning: Skipping data file with no valid points` and `line 0: x range is invalid`, using the line-numbered data from Bernhard. it's quite amazing. I've been using `bash` for years now, and once you start feeling just a little light-headed every caution in regard of quoting strings and escaping everything is - gone. Man, I hope this doen't last all that long...

Comment: @Christian I tested it gnuplot 4.2, so not sure about that. `grep`s output works for you?